# Why I cant get a JSON response from root url in my react app from an express server?

Tags: reactjs, express

This is a simple code that logs a Json request from an express server in the console on clicking a button

One button(b1) is for the root url while the other button(b2) is for a differnt url

The Json request logs normally on different urls like 'a/'
But when I try on the root url '/' it gives this error in the console

*Fetch error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*

This is my express code

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const port = 8000;

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"foo1":"bar"}); 
  });
  
server.get('/a', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"foo1":"bar"}); 
});


server.listen(port,() => console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`))
```

React code

```
function func1(){

    fetch('/')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData))
    .catch(error => console.error("Fetch error:", error));

}

function func2(){

    fetch('/a')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData))
    .catch(error => console.error("Fetch error:", error));

}

function App(){
    return(
<>
    <button onClick={func1}>
        b1
    </button>

    <button onClick={func2}>
        b2
    </button>
    </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

In package.jason

```
  "proxy":"http://localhost:8000",
```

The surprising thing is that error only occurs in the root url while the code is exactly the same

Comment: shouldnt your fetch point to `localhost:8000/` and `localhost:8000/a`

Comment: @Xiduzo I Forgot to mention I added localhost:8000 in proxy so I don't need to add fetch point to localhost:8000/

Comment: is the `/` endpoint being hit (could you do a console log over there) or is it somehow requesting another resource from which it does not get back a JSON

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a prefix like /api/, /api/a to distinguish the express routes from the client routes

Comment: So we can't request from the root url ('/') because the router can distinguish between the routes?

Comment: Even with a proxy, if your React app is served from the root URL ('/'), a fetch request to '/' might still be interpreted as a request for the main HTML page of the React app, not the Express API. This is because the root route is generally reserved for serving the entry point of your client-side application.